# Protractor-flake + Allure = duplicate values in the report

Tags: duplicates, protractor

When using protractor-flake it generates allure report with duplicate values. How to display in report results only on the last re-run?

Comment: Basically I need to display only data from the artifacts for the last build. How is it possible to specify which artifacts to use for the reports or how to delete unnesessary artifacts?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to post your code or we have no idea how to help you. There are an infinite number of ways I can generate an allure report with duplicate values. And an infinite number of reasons why your display doesn't result only on the last re-run.